# Azure APIM ARM deployment doesn't work for Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations representations.sample

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

### Background

I'm using ARM templates to deploy dev/prod APIM instances. One of my APIs takes a request body of "application/xml" text. If I add this in the Azure Portal it will save and show in the Developer Portal:

[image: APIM adding request body example]

When I extract and deploy this to my production APIM instance, I can see that the example representation is in the ARM template, both in my [repo](https://github.com/IATI/apim-iati-gateway/blob/6ec8f609bda0b21d65a4a63fb8ed055146e61ca8/service/apim-iati-dev-apis.template.json#L688-L691) and in the Azure Deployment log [image: ARM Deployment in Portal].

However the sample (xml) part does not actually get deployed and is blank on my production instance.

[image: prod request representation]

### What I've tried

- I found this [article](https://mlogdberg.com/apimanagement/arm-template-creator) that mentions that this is a problem (back in 2017), but I don't want to change my whole deployment strategy because of this one bug.
- I tried to add this as a definition, since my json response definitions worked, but it seems that only JSON is allowed in definitions, not xml.
- Thanks for the idea @Thomas, tried a bunch of different representations.contentType / representations.sample combinations and none are deployed by ARM (the sample shows up as blank in the Portal). So doesn't seem to be related to the special characters.

```
"representations": [
            {
              "contentType": "application/xml",
              "sample": "Hello World"
            },
            {
              "contentType": "application/json",
              "sample": "Hello World"
            },
            {
              "contentType": "text/plain",
              "sample": "Hello World"
            },
            {
              "contentType": "text/xml",
              "sample": "<xml></xml>"
            },
            {
              "contentType": "text/xml",
              "sample": "&lt;xml&gt;&lt;/xml&gt;"
            }
          ]
```

### Question

Has anyone found a workaround for this? Or know how to report it to Microsoft. It seems the [feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager) has been discontinued.

Comment: You can report it to Microsoft via [raise support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/), [Twitter @AzureSupport](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) and also ask the same question on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/)

Comment: did you try to escape the xml ?

Comment: @DeepDave-MT thank you. I don't have a support plan so can't ask for technical help with a support ticket so created a [question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/526088/azure-apim-arm-deployment-doesn39t-work-for-micros.html) on MS Q&A